# Excel VBA For Each select cell on break

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that checks a range for any blank cells, then runs a second macro. At present if a blank cell is found, the user gets a message alerting them of a blank cell, and the macro ends.

I would like to be able to select the blank cell before ending the macro, so the user knows where to find it.

```
Dim e As Range
Set e = Range("A2", Range("A1000").End(xlUp))

For Each Cell In e
    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then
        ActiveCell.Select
        MsgBox ("Please remove empty row")
        Cancel = True
        Application.StatusBar = vbNullString
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

Is there a selector that will leave the empty cell as active?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `ActiveCell.Select` with `Cell.Select`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
Sub test()
Dim e As Range
Set e = Range("A2", Range("A1000").End(xlUp))

For Each Cell In e
    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then
        Cell.Select
        MsgBox ("Please remove empty row")

        Exit Sub
    End If
Next


End Sub
```